# facebook send, follow no longer working in react js

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to bring facebook follow and send button in React.  I have loaded the Sdk script at index.html

```
<div className="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX" data-layout="standard" data-colorscheme="dark" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

And

```
<div id="fb-send" className="fb-send" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/"></div>
```

My index.html is as

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=XXXX&autoLogAppEvents=1';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I did check my browser for html generated. shows as

```
<div class="fb-send fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXX/" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=XXXXX6&amp;container_width=1100&amp;href=XXXXX&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey">
```

Comment: what does the browser console say? and the network tab? is the sdk loaded correctly? show us some javascript code.

Comment: Do i need to reload the sdk in componentdidmount??? or is there is a module for this?? Browser console does not show any thing related to fb

Comment: Btw, I am at locahost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Follow Button is deprecated, but we cannot see developer's sites. https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=follow+graph+api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Social Plugins with React, you have to use this function - for example, in your `componentDidMount`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Be aware that you may need to call this again if the component gets re-rendered. Also, you need to wait until the JS SDK is loaded for sure. Take a look at the fbAsyncInit function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

This thread may help you too: [Integrating Facebook Web SDK with ReactJS Component State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992477/integrating-facebook-web-sdk-with-reactjs-component-state)